# Is OAuth signature credible?

Tags: oauth, signature, data-integrity

I am looking at OAuth1.0A documentation to implement similar protocol. Doing this,  I'm trying to find justification for every element in the request.

I wonder what's signature for. So far I understand that signature can be used to guarantee of data integrity. But, what if a hacker crafts the signature using oauth_signature_method stated in oauth request?

I have known that we can guarantee the sender identity by appending shared secret to base string before encoding. Then, the signature is worth only when shared secret is appended. Right?

Comment: 1) OAuth **must** be communicated through a secured transport layer so a hacker must first intercept a secured layer in order to read the oauth header request and modify the parameters.

I don't quiet follow your last paragraph/statement. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: OAuth has version 2.0 now, and one of the reasons was that OAuth 1.0 had security weaknesses. Moreover, some weaknesses (more implementation-specific than design flaws) were discovered just recently in Oauth 2.0 as well.